# What's the recommended way to use multiple Dart SDK versions?

Tags: dart

I'd need to run Dart SDK `1.24.2` and `2.0.0` for different projects on Windows. When using the [community supported installer](http://www.gekorm.com/dart-windows/), it unfortunately overwrites any previous version, and does not support installing at a different location. I've found this [Dart Version Manager](https://github.com/matanlurey/dvm) which seemed promising, but had no luck with it:

```
$ pub global activate dvm
Resolving dependencies...
Package dvm requires SDK version >=1.22.0 <2.0.0 but the current SDK is 2.0.0.
```

When actually I'm running 1.24.2:

```
$ dart --version
Dart VM version: 1.24.2 (Thu Jun 22 08:55:56 2017) on "windows_x64"
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this? Also, I'd need a no fuss way to change between SDK versions in IntelliJ.

Comment: You can try to install one version(1.24.2) with [choco](https://chocolatey.org/packages/dart-sdk/1.24.2) and the latest stable(2.0.0) with the [community installer](http://www.gekorm.com/dart-windows/).
Then set different dart sdks path in Intellij, by default with choco it is installed in ```C:\tools\```

Answer (score 4):

I just ended up downloading the required versions as zip files from the [archives](https://webdev.dartlang.org/tools/sdk/archive), extracted them at different locations and every time I need to switch SDK version, I

- update the path to point to the right SDK version binaries
- change the path to the selected SDK in IntelliJ

A bit cumbersome but at least works.

Comment: Were you also able to use multiple versions of pub? If so, how?